# Design of FIR and IIR filters in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filter-design, finite-impulse-response, infinite-impulse-response, bandpass

I need to create 4 different pass-band filters. What remains the same throughout is the following:

Sampling Frequency = $3000Hz$

Pass-band Frequency = $900Hz-1200Hz$

Now, these are the filters I am supposed to create:

1. $24^{th}$ order FIR using windowing method with Hamming window.
2. $24^{th}$ order FIR  using frequency sampling.
3. $8^{th}$ order IIR using bilinear transform with Butterworth prototype analogue filter
4. $8^{th}$ order IIR using impulse invariance with Butterworth prototype analogue filter.

My Attempts:

1. Normalised frequencies are $0.6$ and $0.8$ and the filter is 24th order  hence

   ```
   b = fir1(24,[0.6 0.8]);
   ```
2. The Desired frequency response is 
   $$H(\Omega)=\exp^{-12j\Omega}$$ for $$\frac{3\pi}{5}\leq\Omega<\frac{4\pi}{5}$$
   and 
   $$\frac{6\pi}{5}<\Omega\leq\frac{7\pi}{5}$$
   With $$\Omega=\frac{2\pi k}{25}$$
   Hence I have that $H(\Omega)\neq0$ when $k=8,9,16,17$

The function in Matlab that creates this filter is

```
B=fir2(N,f,m)
```

Where $f$ is the vector with sampled frequencies and $m$ is the magnitude at those frequencies. But for my case I have frequencies higher than $1$ at it says that $f$ starts with $0$ and ends with $1$. I kind of guessed the outcome and produced this:

```
f=[0 0.64 0.72 1];
m=[1 exp(-12*j*0.64) exp(-12*j*0.72) exp(-12*j)];
b=fir2(24,f,m)
```

I have a feeling that this is not correct.

3. For the bilinear IIR I went to matlab's "butter" function.

   ```
   [b,a] = butter(4,[0.6 0.8],'stop');
   ```
4. For this part I know I need to use both 'butter' and 'impinvar' together but I don't know how.

EDIT / ATTEMPT:

```
[b1,a1] = butter(4,[2*pi*900 2*pi*1200],'s');
[bz,az] = impinvar(b1,a1,3000);
```

Could someone tell me if my attempts 1-3 are correct and help me out a little with 4? Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `fir1` looks OK, but you should check the result yourself. You could probably answer several of your other questions by carefully reading the mathworks documentation of the respective functions. E.g., for [fir2](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/fir2.html?s_tid=doc_ta) you can read that

> f is a vector of frequency points in the range from 0 to 1, where 1 corresponds to the Nyquist frequency. The first point of f must be 0 and the last point must be 1. f must be sorted in increasing order. Duplicate frequency points are allowed and are treated as steps in the frequency response.

and

> m is a vector containing the desired magnitude response at each of the points specified in f.

So you shouldn't define `m` as a complex vector; the routine knows the phase lag because it's just half of the filter order. The vector `f` should be defined as follows:

`f = [0 .6 .6 .8 .8 1]`

Since this is homework, I leave the definition of the magnitude vector up to you.

Your call to `butter` looks OK, apart from the fact that you used `stop` as the filter type. You want a band pass filter, not a band stop filter, so just leave out the additional filter type argument, and the routine will by default design a band pass filter (because there are two edge frequencies in the frequency vector).

For the impulse invariance method, you first have to design an analog Butterworth filter (using `butter` with last input argument `s` for analog filter), and then use `impinvar` to create the corresponding digital filter. The [mathworks documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/impinvar.html?s_tid=doc_ta) is very clear, and I think you will succeed after having studied it. Otherwise, add to your original question a very specific question where you're stuck.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out here, that definition of the magnitude is problematic. I am not really sure what is meant here. Could you expand on it for me? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @KuderaSebastian: It's just zeros and ones. At frequencies $0$ and $1$ the corresponding magnitudes are zero (because you want a bandpass, right?). The other $4$ values are the edge frequencies. Starting from the left (low frequencies), you go up from $0$ to $1$, and at the other edge you go down from $1$ to $0$.

Comment: Yeah, that was a rather stupid question, but thanks very much for answering. If you could spare another minute, I did attempt part 4 and put it in. Is that what it should look like ?

Comment: @KuderaSebastian: Looks good, but also check the resulting filter, if it actually *is* a band pass with satisfying the specs.